# Difference between functors $\mathbf{C} \to \mathbf{D}$ and $\mathbf{C}^{op} \to \mathbf{D}^{op}$

Tags: category-theory

I'm trying to self-learn category theory using Emily Riehl's *Category Theory in Context*. Exercise 1.3.v asks the difference between a functor $\mathbf{C}\to \mathbf{D}$ and a functor $\mathbf{C}^{op} \to \mathbf{D}^{op}$, and I find that question **incredibly** and frustratingly confusing.

I believe there is no difference other than the way such functors are defined (the second one begins and ends in the opposite categories of $\mathbf{C}$ and $\mathbf{D}$). Say that $\mathbf{F} : \mathbf{C}^{op} \to \mathbf{D}^{op}$ is a functor. For a morphism $f: A \to B$ in $\mathbf{C}$ we have that $f: B \to A$ is a morphism in $\mathbf{C}^{op}$, so that $\mathbf{F}f : \mathbf{F} B \to \mathbf{F} A$ is a morphism in $\mathbf{D}^{op}$, which itself translates to a morphism $\mathbf{F}f : \mathbf{F} A \to \mathbf{F} B$ in $\mathbf{D}$.

However I am having trouble dealing with the image of compositions. Is it okay to say that, by denoting $\circ_{\mathbf{C}}$ and $\circ_{\mathbf{C}^{op}}$ the respective compositions, we have $$\mathbf{F} (g \circ_{\mathbf{C}} f) = \mathbf{F} (f \circ_{\mathbf{C}^{op}} g) = \left( \mathbf{F} f \right)\circ_{\mathbf{D}^{op}} \left(\mathbf{F} g\right) = \left(\mathbf{F} g \right)\circ_{\mathbf{D}} \left(\mathbf{F} f \right)?$$

So essentially, such a functor can be thought as a (covariant) functor between the "non-opposite" categories. Is this an acceptable answer?

Comment: yes; i dont think the question goes much deeper than this. any functor $C\to D$ gives a functor $C^{op}\to D$, and similarly $C^{op}\to D^{op}$. And since $(C^{op})^{op}$ is naturally isomorphic to $C$, functors $C\to D$ are the same data as functors $C^{op}\to D^{op}$.

Comment: @ElliotG Any functor $C\to D$ gives a functor $C^{op}\to D$? That's not right - unless you mean that any *covariant* functor $C\to D$ gives a *contravariant* functor $C^{op}\to D$, in which case omitting the variance is very confusing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are right. There is a high level view on this matter.

Suppose that $\textbf{CAT}$ is a category of (small with respect to given universe) categories. As you may know $\textbf{CAT}$ is a paradigmatic example of a $2$-category. Morphisms of $2$-categories are called $2$-functors. Then the construction of the opposite category may be viewed as the $2$-functor

$$(-)^{op}:\textbf{CAT} \rightarrow \textbf{CAT}$$

which is an (involutive i.e. $(-)^{op}\cdot (-)^{op}= 1_{\textbf{CAT}}$) isomorphism of $2$-categories. This fact in particular implies that $(-)^{op}$ induces an isomorphism of categories of functors

$$\mathrm{Func}\left(\mathcal{C},\mathcal{D}\right)^{\mathrm{op}} \cong \mathrm{Func}\left(\mathcal{C}^{op},\mathcal{D}^{op}\right)$$

This is a rigorous formulation of the phenomenon you've discovered.

Comment: Don't you mean $\operatorname{Func}(C,D)^{op} = \operatorname{Func}(C^{op},D^{op})$?

Comment: No. The $2$-functor $(-)^{op}$ sends a functor $F:\mathcal{C}\rightarrow \mathcal{D}$ to a functor $F^{\mathrm{op}}:\mathcal{C}^{op}\rightarrow \mathcal{D}^{op}$. So $F\mapsto F^{op}$ induces an isomorphism $\mathrm{Func}(\mathcal{C},\mathcal{D}) \rightarrow \mathrm{Func}(\mathcal{C}^{op},\mathcal{D}^{op})$.

Comment: But natural transformation between functors are reversed under $(-)^{op}$ making it contravariant.

Comment: @NoelLundström Ah! Now I see what you meant. Yes, you are right. Thank you for great comment and useful comment.

Comment: Thank you @Slup for your kind words a year after I posted the comment lol